# iOS Recognize that a touch was made but don't intercept it

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uigesturerecognizer, uiresponder

I have a view that I am showing.  The view appears on the same screen with UITableView.  I want to dismiss the view when anywhere on the screen is touched, but I don't want to prevent that touch from getting to its target.  For instance, if the user goes to scroll the table view or select a cell or anything - I want to know so I can dismiss the view but I want whatever the user was touching to react as it normally would.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `hitTest:withEvent:` method on that UIView's class. Check the location of the touch. If your view's frame does not contain it - dismiss the view.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
  UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

 CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: touch.view];
  if(CGRectContainsPoint(tableView.frame, location) || CGRectContainsPoint(anyOtherObject.frame, location))
 {
    [self performAction];
 }
[self.view removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a UIPopover or UIActionSheet, it will exhibit this behavior almost exactly. I have done this on a UITableView and a UITableView embedded in a UIView.